# Wireshark does not list USB HID mouse or keyboard

Tags: usb, wireshark

I have installed Wireshark 3.05 and USBPcap 1.2.0.4 on a Windows 10 machine (Version 10.0.18362.418) to sniff some USB communication from devices. Wireshark shows me three USBPcap interfaces after start:

[image]

Interface 1 and 2 give me results like this

[image]

But I get some sort of changing data after starting interface 3.

[image]

So I want to sniff the communication with my USB mouse (Logitech G5). I checked the device manager for the VIDs of the mouse devices and set the filter in Wireshark

[image]

[image]

But Wireshark doesn´t list any input from that mouse. I got the same result when I try the second mouse from the device manager.

So what is going wrong here?